# jest cannot find module 'graphql-request'

Tags: javascript, jestjs, graphql

I creating a es6 javascript webpack project where i am using graphql-request node module. The project runs perfectly fine during runtime but when i run unit test using jest `yarn test`, i m running into

```
Cannot find module 'graphql-request' from 'xyx/abc.js'

    Require stack:
      xyx/abc.js
      tests/abc.test.js

at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jestresolve/build/index.js:306:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/abc.js:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/abc.test.js:1:44)
```

After a lot of google search, I was able to get it resolved by following the solution suggested here [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53466859/jest-cannot-find-module-from-node-modules/75595580#75595580) by adding the main entry to the package.json file of the graphql-request module in the `node_modules/graphql-request`. This hack would work in my local but not in other environments where the project would be built again. What would be the ideal fix be ?

graphql-request version `5.2.0`
jest version `26.6.3`
node `19.8.1`