# Why can't Jest find a module in node_modules, but my app can?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have a Vue3 app that uses [jsgrowup2](https://github.com/spoon-foundation/jsgrowup2), a library that I (inexpertly) wrote. Importing it works fine in the app in the browser, but when I go to run unit tests with Jest, they fail with the error

```
Cannot find module 'jsgrowup2' from 'src/models/GrowthAssessment.ts'
```

The import statement it's failing on is:

```
import { Observation, SexSpecification } from "jsgrowup2"
```

I suspect that the build process for the jsgrowup2 is somehow problematic, but for what it's worth, here is my jest config and tsconfig for the Vue app:

```
// jest.config.js
export default {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
  },
}

// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["./cypress.config.ts", "node_modules", "cypress", "**/*.cy.tsx"]
}
```

I tried clearing the jest cache, to no avail.

```
./node_modules/.bin/jest --clearCache
```

I tried editing `jsgrowup2`'s `package.json` to include a "main" attribute (per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68724825/697143)).

```
"main": "dist/index.mjs",
```

No dice.